# what happend to tensorflow ScaleAndShift from r0.12?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distribution

I am currently using tensorflow version 1.0.0, and trying to use a code from tensorflow r0.12 where I used a ScaleAndShift like this

```
    from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import TransformedDistribution
    from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.bijector import ScaleAndShift
    td = TransformedDistribution( distribution=olde,bijector=ScaleAndShift(shift=30.0, scale=60.0))
```

According to API this is still possible with some little change. They provide this example :

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/TransformedDistribution?authuser=3

```
    ds = tf.contrib.distributions
    normal = ds.TransformedDistribution(
      distribution=ds.Normal(mu=0, sigma=1),
      bijector=ds.bijector.ScaleAndShift(loc=mu, scale=sigma, event_ndims=0),
      name="NormalTransformedDistribution")
```

However, I get this error message :

```
    >>> ds.TransformedDistribution(
    ...   distribution=ds.Normal(mu=0., sigma=1.),
    ...   bijector=ds.bijector.ScaleAndShift(loc=mu, scale=sigma,   event_ndims=0),
    ...   name="NormalTransformedDistribution")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ScaleAndShift'
```

Which unfortunately seems quite consistent with the repo on git where I can't seem to find any such thing as ScaleAndShitf

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug posted, and correction applied by tf team.

Answer (score 0):

For posteriority, tf.contrib.distributions.bijectors.ScaleAndShift has turned in to:

- tf.contrib.distributions.bijectors.AffineScalar, doing something like ax + b (i.e. the bijector acts on scalars and broadcasts up).
- tf.contrib.distributions.bijectors.Affine, doing something like Ax + b (i.e. the bijector acts on vectors and broadcasts up).